# ngAnimate object not set to a function

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm running into an error when using ngAnimate and ui-view. Onload or clicking any navigation menu; the angular-animate.js generates a 'object is not a function' error.

Here the main javacsript app:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var app = angular.module("pie", ['ui.router', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate']);

app.config(["$stateProvider", "$locationProvider", "$urlRouterProvider",
function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Welcome');
    $stateProvider
        .state("Welcome", {
            url: "/Welcome",
            templateUrl: "../Scripts/Home/WelcomeView.html",
            controller: "WelcomeController"
        })
        .state("About", {
            url: "/About",
            templateUrl: "../Scripts/Home/AboutView.html",
            controller: "AboutController"
        })
        .state("Contact", {
            url: "/Contact",
            templateUrl: "../Scripts/Home/ContactView.html",
            controller: "ContactController"
        })
        .state("Login", {
            url: "/Account/Login"
        })
        .state("Register", {
            url: "/Account/Register"
        })
        .state("ForgotPassword", {
            url: "/Account/ForgotPassword"
        });
}]);

//app.animation('.view-animation', function () {
//    return {
//        enter: function (element, done) {
//            element.css({
//                opacity: 0.5,
//                position: "relative",
//                top: "10px",
//                left: "20px"
//            }).animate({
//                top: 0,
//                left: 0,
//                opacity: 1
//            }, 1000, done);
//        }
//    };
//});

app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    //Http Intercpetor to check auth failures for xhr requests
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthHttpResponseInterceptor');
}]);

// Google map
app.config(['uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider', function (uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        //    key: 'your api key',
        v: '3.17',
        libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
    });
}
]);

}());
```

Surprisingly the animation seems to work, but I would prefer solving the error:

This is where the error is generated from in Angular-anumate.js:

```
function fireDoneCallbackAsync() {
                                          fireDOMCallback('close');
                                          if (doneCallback) {
                                              $$asyncCallback(function () {
                                                  doneCallback();
                                              });
                                          }
                                      }
```

I'm using vs2013 as IDE, all the javascripts files and libraries are inserted at the bottom of the page; I tried injecting through the bundle or regular script as show, but no differences:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angularjs")
@*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angularAnimate")*@
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundle/app")
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**EDITED**
Even when I comment the app.animation call the error remains (see code above). 
Just injecting the ngAnimate will generate the error

```
var app = angular.module("pie", ['ui.router', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate']);
```

Can the IIFE be the cause?

Comment: It seems that the "done" function is what is causing your issue. The expected input is function(element, className, from, to, done) , where from and to are required, so it thinks done is your from, one should be an object but the other not? See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something really important to remember when using `ngAnimate` is that the `ngAnimate` version must be the same as the angular version you're using.

That is to say if you're using v 1.3.4 of angular, you should use v 1.3.4 of angular animate.

Since including the library alone is giving you the error, I expect your versions are not in sync.

Comment: Thanks. That was it. Angular core installed from Nugets was 1.3.2 and ngAnimate 1.2.27. I've done quite a lot of research, and never come accross this requirement.

Comment: Ah. This one got me too. It would be nice if there was some kind of warning message to let you know that you're using versions that are out of sync.

Comment: @Don, agreed - I was able to answer this question quickly because it's happened to me quite a few times! This would make a great pull request for [ngHint](https://github.com/angular/angular-hint)